# Is there a way to add data validation to a column without knowing the specific number of rows?

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I am pretty new to openpyxl and spreadsheet generation in general, so sorry in advance if this is a dumb question.

At my work, we use a spreadsheet generator that generates a full spreadsheet based on a JSON schema. We want that spreadsheet to be filled later by other people, to transform it back to JSON and make it flow through our system.

We have some fields that are enums, with a limited option of accepted values determined within the JSON schema. We currently accept free text to be filled in, and later it gets validated and throws an error if the free text is not one of the options.

We were thinking about adding data validation to the spreadsheet, but one of the problems that arose was that we don't know how many rows will the person with the spreadsheet fill. So, the question is: **Is there any way to specify that only certain values are allowed for a specific column without specifying the number of rows that are going to be filled?**

(For some more info, we use python 3 and the library openpyxl to generate the spreadsheet)

Thanks!

Comment: You can do this in theory, but in practice Excel always specifies the maximum number of rows for the relevant range and openpyxl will only accept complete ranges (columns and rows).

Comment: Thanks! So, unless we specify the amount of rows it's not possible :/ The amounts of rows is not massive, so we might end up giving a the options with an option to "" to the first 1000 rows and we could work with that for now

Comment: FWIW 1048576 is the maximum number of rows allowed in a worksheet. You can always use this. It has no cost for openpyxl.